# Manage CORS between Google App Engine & Google Cloud Function

Tags: express, google-app-engine, cors

I'm trying to set up a new instance of a simple App Engine which communicate with a backend-function hosted on Google Cloud Function. The App Engine is protected with IAP, and the Google Cloud Function is private only. The GAE use Angular Framework and GCF use Node 14 with Express
.

I can't access to my GCF from the App Engine because the requests are blocked by CORS.
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I tried the popular solutions on the web :

1. Use the `cors` librairie on the GCF. So I had on my GCF

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true })))
```

And I also add this line for every request

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
```

2. Add the http-header on my app.yaml

```
handlers:
  - url: /(.*\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4})$
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.*\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4})$
    http_headers: 
      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
  - url: /(.*)$
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
    http_headers: 
      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

But I still get the same error message.

EDIT : so the first problem was due to an authentication issue, that why the error have the same response. So I decided to deploy the 2 apps on App Engine to simplify communication between the 2 services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can now have full access to the HTTP Request/Responses by setting
  the appropriate CORS headers as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests).
- Just so you know the reason for the error you are facing, it is
  because when your web browser is calling a service that is in a
  different/cross domain, it doesn’t make a HTTP request right away, it
  rather starts with making an OPTIONS request( a preflight request)
  and compares the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the
  result with the current domain i.e. it checks for this  (req.method
  === 'OPTIONS') in the headers and if the header value matches the host, the actual call is made, otherwise the action is stopped and
  the error as the one above is thrown.
- To have a thorough understanding of the above concept, have a look at
  this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/15803365) and read this [article](https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/) for more insights.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. BTW the first problem was due to an authentication issue, that why the error was always the same. I decided to deploy the 2 apps on App Engine to simplify communication between the 2 services. But it learn me a lot about the cors.

Comment: That's great. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @DamDam What do you mean? Are you saying you were being blocked by CORS due to an authentication issue (i.e., not `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`)?